# Detect which /dev/ttyACM is open

Tags: python, bash, tty

Is their a command that returns what `/dev/ttyACM*` is open. At some stage in the script it disconnects the usb and reconnects but the ACM increments after this so the variable `port = /dev/ttyACM0` now is `/dev/ttyACM1`. I want to detect which /dev/ttyACM* is open. So `port = return (command  to find ACM)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `glob` and `serial`, this should do the trick:

```
import glob
import serial

def find_ports():
    ports = glob.glob('/dev/ttyACM[0-9]*')

    res = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            res.append(port)
        except:
            pass
    return res
```